# QEMU KVM Black Screen

Tags: uefi, qemu, android

I have KVM enabled on my phone and it works, but it stays on a black screen except for QEMU Monitor `stdio` (But it only shows text like Press a key to boot from CD/DVD.  In GUI sections, a line flashes).  When I enter commands such as `-device VGA`, it remains as a black screen.  I am using QEMU ARM64 (`qemu-system-aarch64`) with Termux 0.118 and I am using VNC Viewer for image

My phone specs:

Redmi Note 10S (Secret) 6/128

MediaTek Helio G95 (MT6785)

Android 11 (R)

Mali G76 MC4 GPU

My parameter:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -m 2G -smp 8 -M virt -cpu host -monitor stdio -device nec-usb-xhci -device usb-kbd -device usb-mouse -usb -accel kvm -hda /sdcard/arm64.qcow2 -device intel-hda   -vnc 127.0.0.1:2 -accel 3d -device VGA -bios /sdcard/QEMU_EFI.img
```

NOTE: When I start the machine I get a message like this but it works:

```
(qemu) qemu-system-aarch64: warning: ITS KVM: full reset is not supported by the host kernel
```

Comment: Questions about phones are offtopic. You might want to ask at [XDA](https://www.xda-developers.com/) or [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by doing `-device ramfb` instead of `-device VGA` and OVMF with `-pflash` instead of `-bios`.

My parameter:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -m 2G -smp 8 -M virt -cpu host -monitor stdio -device nec-usb-xhci -device usb-kbd -device usb-mouse -usb -accel kvm -hda /sdcard/arm64.qcow2 -device intel-hda  -vnc 127.0.0.1:2 -accel 3d -device ramfb -pflash /sdcard/flash0.img -pflash /sdcard/flash1.img
```